# Using Eval for creating Comma Separated string from Generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, repeater

I have a Report class. The reports data is rendered using a repeater control. There is a department list (generic list of string)  to be displayed as comma separated. Can we make it as a comma separated list in the repeater using Eval? If we cannot use Eval, is there any other syntax for this in repeater?

Class

```
 public class Report
{
    public int ReportID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Recipients { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public List<string> DepartmentList { get; set; }

}
```

ASP.NET Markup

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptReports" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <div>
                        </div>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="repeaterIdentifier">
                            <div class="reportTitle">
                                <%# Eval("Title") +":" %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="reportFrequency">
                                <%# " Frequency - "+ Eval("Frequency") %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reportContent">
                            <div class="repeaterLine">
                                <%# Eval("Recipients")%></div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
<%#String.Join(",",((Report)Container.DataItem).DepartmentList)%>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <%# String.Join((List<string>)Eval("DepartmentList")).ToArray()) %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Note: code not tested

Comment: This answer helped me the most for my setup.  Tested code version:

`<%# String.Join(", ",(List<string>)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DepartmentList")) %>`

Answer (score 1):

In your class `Report`, you may want to add an extra property

```
public string DepartmentListCommas
{
  get
  {
     return string.Join(", ", DepartmentList);
  }
}
```